# Inner div strictly contained in outer div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the item (inner div) to be fully contained inside the container/wrapper (outer div). That is, even if the content overflows in the inner div it will not spill over and overlaps with the outer div padding.
[Code Sample Of The Problem](https://codepen.io/hirosanza/pen/xxaxPeL)

```css
.inner {
  /* Overflow */
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}

.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
  </div> </div>
```

I expect it to be like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pcNi.png)
where the inner div can be as long as it needs to.

I have tried multiple different kinds of overflow settings. I also used "border" instead of padding. The inner div keeps overflowing the outer div regardless.

Comment: You took the time to add the relevant CSS, and linked to the "code sample of the problem," why didn't you post that "*[mcve]*" code here in your question? Hint: please post that relevant, required code *here* in your question.

Comment: I've converted your code here into a functioning snippet.  It appears to be functioning as expected -- the outer element's `overflow: hidden` is hiding the content from the inner element that doesn't fit.   (The inner element's `overflow` rule is doing nothing and can be removed). Can you clarify what unexpected behavior you're seeing?

Comment: ...wait a minute.  Did you incorporate Ryan's answer below into the question in the edit before mine?  Please don't do that, if that in fact was the problem with your code; it makes the question useless for future users because they can't see what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
.inner {
  /* Overflow */
  height: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  color: white;
}
```

Adding `height: 100%` to the `.inner` container solves this problem - you need to tell the inner container how tall you want it to display - or it will display to the height of the content inside of it.

`Height: 100%` only works here because you have explictly set a height on one of the parent containers of `.inner`, in this case `.outer` has a height of `100px`

Comment: This did answer the question - thank you. Just as you point out, it does not work if the height is not fixed. In my case, I have to deal with a dynamic sandbox and can only rely on max-height. My question comes rather short.